# How to return a boolean using indexOf() instead of includes()?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am doing a calculator challenge and when I started to solve the part of the decimal dot it gives me unexpected behavior. I made a function called input digit that, when the decimal point key is clicked, I need to append a decimal point to a number that already exists in the display. 
Inside the function, I used an if statement to check if the property of the object doesn't  include a dot by using `(...)indexOf(dot) === -1` or `!(...).includes(dot)`  , if not I will add to that property object the dot. But the result in the browser is, when I click the dot, it shows me two dots instead of one and I was wonder what I am doing wrong.

This is my code so far:

```js
const calculator = {
  displayValue: '0',
  firstOperand: null,
  waitingForSecondOperand: false,
  operator: null
};

function inputDigit(digit) {

  const {
    displayValue
  } = calculator;
  calculator.displayValue = displayValue === '0' ? digit : displayValue + digit;

}

//*here is the function that adds a dot* 
function inputDecimal(dot) {
  if (!calculator.displayValue.includes(dot)) {
    calculator.displayValue += dot;
  }
}

function updateDisplay() {
  const display = document.querySelector('#screen');
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
}

updateDisplay();

const keys = document.querySelector('.calculator-keys');

keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  const {
    target
  } = e; // is equivalent to const target = event.target;

  if (!target.matches('button')) {
    return;
  }

  if (target.classList.contains('operator')) {
    console.log('operator', target.value);
    return;
  }

  if (target.classList.contains('decimal')) {
    inputDecimal(target.value);
    updateDisplay();

  }

  if (target.classList.contains('all-clear')) {
    console.log('clear', target.value);
    return;
  }

  inputDigit(target.value);
  // /
  updateDisplay();

});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.calculator {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
}

.calculator-screen {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5rem;
  height: 80px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #333;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .04));
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .05), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .45), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.operator {
  color: #337cac;
}

.all-clear {
  background-color: #f0595f;
  border-color: #b0353a;
  color: #fff;
}

.all-clear:hover {
  background-color: #f17377;
}

.equal-sign {
  background-color: #2e86c0;
  border-color: #337cac;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 6 / 5;
}

.equal-sign:hover {
  background-color: #4e9ed4;
}

.calculator-keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">

  <input type="text" id="screen" class="calculator-screen" value="" disabled />
  <div class="calculator-keys">

    <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

    <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" value="9">9</button>

    <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="6">6</button>

    <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="3">3</button>

    <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="decimal function" value=".">.</button>
    <button type="button" class="all-clear function" value="all-clear">AC</button>

    <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code appears to miss the definition of `dot`?

Comment: I've added your code to a Stack Snippet to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow. To do that, I changed your code a little; one, I move an asterisk inside a comment, and commented out a seemingly out of place slash `/`. Please do [edit] your question and the snippet if I've inadvertently changed something.

Comment: You have a check for decimal with an `if` and  few lines later you use the `inputDigit(target.value);` You have a logic problem.

Comment: Just looks like you're missing a `return;` at the end of the `if (target.classList.contains('decimal')) {` block.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey first because of the observations of the post, where I should do better, and because of your answer to the problem.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addEventListener` code, since you are handling all cases except the numbers, for all event listeners the `inputDigit(target.value)` function would be called for each type of button click, whether it is number, decimal or operator. Hence while adding the decimal there are two functions which are called `inputDecimal` and `inputDigit`, this is the reason you are getting two decimal point at each decimal button click.

To avoid this you can simply add the 'digit' class for all of your digit input like below

```
  <button type="button" value="1" class="digit">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2" class="digit">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3" class="digit">3</button>
```

And in event listener you can add the following code

```
if (target.classList.contains('digit')) {
  inputDigit(target.value);
  updateDisplay();
}
```

The complete code for HTML is

```
<div class="calculator">
  <input type="text" id="screen" class="calculator-screen" value="" disabled />
  <div class="calculator-keys">
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

    <button type="button" value="7" class="digit">7</button>
    <button type="button" value="8" class="digit">8</button>
    <button type="button" value="9" class="digit">9</button>

    <button type="button" value="4" class="digit">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="5" class="digit">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="6" class="digit">6</button>

    <button type="button" value="1" class="digit">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="2" class="digit">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="3" class="digit">3</button>

    <button type="button" value="0" class="digit">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="decimal function" value=".">.</button>
    <button type="button" class="all-clear function" value="all-clear">AC</button>

    <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the JavaScript code is

```
<script>
  const calculator = {
    displayValue: '0',
    firstOperand: null,
    waitingForSecondOperand: false,
    operator: null
  };

  function inputDigit(digit) {

    const { displayValue } = calculator;
    calculator.displayValue = displayValue === '0' ? digit : displayValue + digit;
  }

  function inputDecimal(dot) {
    if (!calculator.displayValue.includes(dot)) {
      calculator.displayValue += dot;
    }
  }

  function updateDisplay() {
    const display = document.querySelector('#screen');
    display.value = calculator.displayValue;
  }

  updateDisplay();

  const keys = document.querySelector('.calculator-keys');

  keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const { target } = e; // is equivalent to const target = event.target;
    if (!target.matches('button')) {
      return;
    }
    if (target.classList.contains('operator')) {
      return;
    }
    if (target.classList.contains('decimal')) {
      inputDecimal(target.value);
      updateDisplay();
    }
    if (target.classList.contains('all-clear')) {
      console.log('clear', target.value);
      return;
    }
    if (target.classList.contains('digit')) {
      inputDigit(target.value);
      updateDisplay();
    }
  });
</script>
```